# Problems with empty initial constraint set & 'deriveConstraintsFrom' on motion layout

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I currently going my first steps into motion layout.

The example I want to create is the following:

[image: Wanted Result]

*A motion layout with two FABs in it (a mini and a normal one). The image above shows the end state after clicking the normal sized FAB.*

---

**What I've tried:**

Motion Layout (is part of an other layout file):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
            android:id="@+id/include"
            app:motionDebug="SHOW_PATH"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layoutDescription="@xml/menu_scene"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/images_button"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/menu_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/menu_button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/menu_button"

                android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
                app:fabSize="mini" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/menu_button"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

MotionScene:

```
<MotionScene xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end">

        <OnClick
            app:targetId="@+id/menu_button"
            app:clickAction="toggle" />
    </Transition>
<!-- pulls constraints from layout -->
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start" />

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/images_button">
            <Layout
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

But unfortunately with this configuration I got this:

[image: wrong result]

*The tiny pink dot on the bottom left is the mini FAB.*

---

Because I heard about [deriveConstraintsFrom](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/ref/constraintset) I gave it a chance:

```
<MotionScene ...>

    <Transition ...>
       ...
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start" />

    <ConstraintSet
        android:id="@+id/end"
        app:deriveConstraintsFrom="@id/start">

        <Constraint android:id="@id/images_button">
           ...
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

But I got the same result! :(

---

The only way I got the wanted result was with the following constraint set configuration:

```
<MotionScene ...>

    ...

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start" />

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/images_button">

            <!--  duplicated the layout properties from the initial layout :( -->
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/menu_button"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

**Wrap up:**

I thought the empty constraint set `<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start" />` pulls the its contrains from the layout itself and `app:deriveConstraintsFrom="@id/start"` on the other constraint set specifies all constraints from the initial constraint set and overwrites its own.

Can somebody tell me why this isn't working? Or did I miss something?

Thanks, Chris

PS.: I using `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4`